# LSTM on Data Shaped (11709, 25,4435) doesnt work

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a data set of the following sort: 
11709 instances, where each has 25 features, and each feature contains an array of one hot encoded vector of size 4435.
The label vector is one hot encoded vector of size 3, i.e. we have 3 labels.

I try to run the following lstm:

```
from keras import layers
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, MaxPooling1D , Dropout, Flatten,Activation,LSTM


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, input_shape=(11709, 25)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(LSTM(3, input_shape=(4435, 25)))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
    `
```

When I run the code, it returns the following error:
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_77 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,).

Anyone has any clues? I saw a bunch of solutions to this error but none helped.

When I run my training_set.shape, it returns (11709, 25) and not (11709, 25,4435) as I thought would happen.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide your input train data shape